# GothamBold font is not working correctly on safari

Tags: html, css

GothamBold font is not displayed correctly on Safari. It is not working properly with display:flex as well. Is there any way to solve this issue?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GothamBold';
  src: url(assets/fonts/GothamBold.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Try .woff2 formate as well

Comment: Have you tried to include .otf too?

Comment: Thank to all of you! It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your font like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```